# how to select the parent field using jquery

Tags: jquery

my main file is

```
<div id="man">
//some content
<div id="one">
//some content
<div id="two">
//some content
<div id="three">
//some content
<div id="four">
<a title="to delete">delete</a>
<a title="to reset">reset</a>
<a title="to change">change</a>
</div>...// all div ends...


<div id="woman">
//some content
<div id="one">
//some content
<div id="two">
//some content
<div id="three">
//some content
<div id="four">
<a title="to delete">delete</a>
<a title="to reset">reset</a>
<a title="to change">change</a>
</div>...// all div ends...
```

and the jquery is -

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$("a:contains(delete)").click(function(){
alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id"))
})
})
```

is there any another way to find the top parent instead of using this...??

Comment: You mean, aside from directly selecting by id (i.e. `$('#woman')`)? If your `<div>`s have IDs, you'd probably be better off selecting directly.

Comment: It should be `$(document)` instead of `$('document')` (even though the selector is completely ignored for the ready event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify your html slightly and give those top-level divs a common class:

```
<div id="man" class="top">
...
<div id="woman" class="top">
```

...then you can use the [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select them:

```
$("a:contains(delete)").click(function(){
   alert($(this).closest('div.top').attr("id"))
})
```

Note that your current html markup is invalid because you are not supposed to give the same `id` to more than one element. (So given that you should change your markup to fix that it will be no problem to also add a class to the top-level divs.)

EDIT: Demonstration that the above works even when "man" and "woman" aren't at the top level: http://jsfiddle.net/NVQXq/

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is the top or not. Notice I said to _change your html_ to add a `class="top"` attribute on the "man" and "woman" divs. The selector `'div.top'` that I used then finds a div with that class. (The class does not have to be called "top", it can be called anything you like.)

Comment: what if there is a another class above ("man") class. than how to search

Comment: @Lokesh `class="top"` has nothing to do with what is actually on top in your html. It's just a class name he made up signifying the top-level element for your problem

Comment: @Lokesh - take a look at the demo I added to the end of my answer (http://jsfiddle.net/NVQXq/) - it has an extra two divs surrounding "man" and "woman" and my jQuery works as is. Read the `.closest()` doco I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you must stick rigidly to that html structure (can't add classes, etc.) then you can certainly make use of the structure in your selector;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a:contains(delete)").click(function(){
        var pId = $(this).parents("#man").attr("id") ||
            $(this).parents("#woman").attr("id");
        alert(pId);
    });
});
```

This is also assuming that your html is well-formed (i.e that your divs for man are all closed).

Since IDs are unique (or should be, though not all of yours are...) and the "man" and "woman" elements must be disjoint, an element can only ever be the child of one or the other -- and since this selector would be bound to a link in one of the two, you know that if its parent isn't a "man" it must be a "woman".

Comment: +1. `pId = $(this).parents("#man,#woman").attr("id");` will work too.

Comment: P.S. As a variation on my answer, `$(this).closest("#man,#woman").attr("id")` also worked.

Comment: @nnnnnn True, that's clever. :)